# MongoDB upsert an array field in a document or simply use objects

Tags: mongodb, upsert

For example, we have collection of people, each like this.

```
{name : 'john'}
```

Now I want to add an array field called girlsfriends, so like

```
{name : 'john', girlfriends: ['Stacy']}
```

How is this generally done? Do it in two steps in application code?

1. Check if `girlfriends` field exists on `person` document?
2. a. if not exists: $set person `girlsfriends` to ['Stacy']

   b. if exists: push element to array?

So either do this or 
simply initialize the array field to `[]` on each document creation? Or some just use objects? generate a random ID as key?

Is there benefit to use array over object? Seems like quite a hassle with the queries..

**Edit:** 
Alright never mind. I shoulda just tried the $push method.. For anyone that comes across, the MongoDB doc is a bit ambiguous when it says

> If the field is not an array, the operation will fail.

If the field doesn't exist, it will create it for you... ofc it will.. its mongo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the `$push` or `$addToSet` operators in an update query.

If the array doesn't exist it will be created by these operators.
The `$addToSet` will keep only unique elements in your array, so that you don't need to check if it's already inside the array.

Here's the full query:

```
db.<your_collection>.updateOne({name:'John'},{$addToSet:{girlfriends:'Stacy'}})
```

Proof:

```
> db.toto.insertOne({name:"John"})
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("5d2f325cf1789f14256be87a")
}
> db.toto.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d2f325cf1789f14256be87a"), "name" : "John" }
> db.toto.updateOne({name:"John"},{$addToSet:{girlfriends:"Stacy"}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.toto.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d2f325cf1789f14256be87a"), "name" : "John", "girlfriends" : [ "Stacy" ] }
```

> Is there benefit to use array over object?

Well, that's a long subject. But long story short, the only time you might be tempted to use an object instead of an array is in case of a Map. For example:

```
"map": {
  "id1": "value1",
  "id2": "value2",
  "id3": "value3"
}
```

I would definitely recommend **NOT** to use this structure as it's really hard to maintain and index.
Instead I would recommend using this structure:

```
"map": [
  { key:"id1", value: "value1" },
  { key:"id2", value: "value2" },
  { key:"id3", value: "value3" }
]
```

You can then index each field separately.

Answer (score 1):

No. This can be done in a single step. Refer [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

```
db.collectionName.update({'name' : 'John'}, {"$push" : {"gf" : "Stacy"}});
db.collectionName.update({'name' : 'John'}, {"$push" : {"gf" : "Nikki"}});
```

If the array field doesn't exist, it will create one, otherwise, append to it.

Comment: You can't push to a nonexisting array field

Comment: If the array field doesn't exist, it will create one, otherwise, append to it.

Comment: ok i checked. you can lol. the doc should explain... it says push to a non array field will fail...  a nonexisting field is no an array..